# Why cannot retrieve data from Firebase realtime database using query and child event listener?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

Currently I try to combine query and child event listener to my project. I using onChildAdded to retrieve data from realtime database and send it to another activity through intend method to the map activity.

Here is my database.
[image]

I am trying to retrieve the data of "UTHM" when user inserted the tracking ID of "UTHM". The program should query the user inserted text from the reference, then retrieve the data from the node, Tracking ID.

I have tried to use child event listener to retrieve the data.
Below is how I apply the coding.

```
 private void isTrackingID() {
        String userTrackingID = enterTracking.getText().toString().trim();

        //Long userTrackingIDNumber = Long.parseLong(userTrackingID);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Tracking ID = " + userTrackingID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("HostID");
        //DatabaseReference trackingRef = rootRef.child("tracking");
        //Query query = trackingRef.orderByChild("id").equalTo(userTrackingID);

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("HostID");

        Query query = reference.orderByChild("Reference/ID").equalTo(userTrackingID);

        query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                    Log.i("checking", "this is value message");

                    enterTracking.setError(null);

                    //String IDfromDatabase = dataSnapshot.child(userTrackingID).getValue(String.class);

                    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        latitudefromDatabase = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot1.child("HostLocation").child("latitude").getValue());
                        Log.i("testing for latitude", latitudefromDatabase);
                        longitudefromDatabase = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot1.child("HostLocation").child("longitude").getValue());
                        Log.i("testing for longitude", longitudefromDatabase);
                        String hostUID = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot1.child("Reference").child("uid").getValue());
                        String customerAddress = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot1.child("TrackingID").child(userTrackingID).child("customerAddress").getValue());
                        String customerReplyStatus = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot1.child("TrackingID").child(userTrackingID).child("customerReplyStatus").getValue());
                        String id = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot1.child("TrackingID").child(userTrackingID).child("id").getValue());
                        String latitude = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot1.child("TrackingID").child(userTrackingID).child("latitude").getValue());
                        String longitude = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot1.child("TrackingID").child(userTrackingID).child("longitude").getValue());
                        String status = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot1.child("TrackingID").child(userTrackingID).child("status").getValue());

                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MapsActivity.class);

                        intent.putExtra("hostUID", hostUID);
                        intent.putExtra("hostlatitude", latitudefromDatabase);
                        intent.putExtra("hostlongitude", longitudefromDatabase);
                        intent.putExtra("customerAddress",customerAddress);
                        intent.putExtra("customerReplyStatus",customerReplyStatus);
                        intent.putExtra("id",id);
                        intent.putExtra("latitude",latitude);
                        intent.putExtra("longitude",longitude);
                        intent.putExtra("status",status);

                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                }else {
                    enterTracking.setError("Invalid Tracking ID from database");
                    enterTracking.requestFocus();
                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });


    }
```

Now the program can detect the user inserted the tracking ID from the reference. However, the program fail to retrieve the data from the node, Tracking ID. Guys, is there have any solution on it?

------------**Update**---------------

I have try to use ValueEventListerner for my program. The program work fine and can retrieve the data. However, when there is changes in the database, the program will refresh the whole map activity as all the data retrieve through the intent method. Someone suggest me to use the childEventListener to solve the problems. So, now the problem return to the origin, how to apply child event listener and query together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The map activity gets refreshed every time because every time new data comes you start a new intent.

Following code will do as it will only get called once so the map is not refreshed every time:

Replace

```
addValueEventListener()
```

with

```
addListenerForSingleValueEvent()
```

Then in your maps activity add a ValueEventListener to get all the live data without refreshing the map

Comment: Why cannot use childEventListerner?

Comment: Sorry, I missread your question. I will start writing another answer as I know where the problem is. Give me a minute...

Comment: I have use the addValueEventListener, the result is like the updated in the post. The program can retrieve the data, however, the program will refresh the whole map activity when there is data changes in the database. I want to make the changes on the value only, but not the whole map activity. Someone suggest me to use child event listener and the problem I faced is as shown in the post.

Comment: If you can retrieve data, but you have the refreshing problem, then my newest answer (this one) should now work for you.

Comment: I have tried this. The program can get the data. But when there have changes on the database, the data in map activity won't update or refresh automatically.

Comment: What about adding a standart listener in your map activity and there you only update the values and the things you need but not the map itself? Like a ValueEventListener in your "MapsActivity"

Comment: Do you mean only pass the main data that get from query such as the HostID and TrackingID (inserted by user), then get the data using datasnapshot in the Map Activity?

Comment: Yes, pass the data that you only need to retrieve one time and then in the map Activity make a listener that listens for data such as position and updates it without refreshing the activity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233021/discussion-between-excited-aid-and-ctrl-see).

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. Since you're using a `ChildEventListener`, your `onChildAdded` will get called for each child that matches the query. This means you don't need to loop over `dataSnapshot` in there, as the Firebase client already does that for you.

So you can just remove the loop from your `onChidAdded` and it'll start working:

```
Query query = reference.orderByChild("Reference/ID").equalTo(userTrackingID);

query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
        // if (dataSnapshot.exists()) { //  not needed, as dataSnapshot is @NonNull in onChildAdded

            Log.i("checking", "this is value message");

            enterTracking.setError(null);

            // for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) { //  not needed, as onChildAdded is already called for the individual child notes matching the query

            latitudefromDatabase = dataSnapshot.child("HostLocation/latitude").getValue(String.class);
            ...
```

Comment: Where does the "dataSnapshot1" come from? You didn't declare it

Comment: I have try to use your coding, the program can get the data. However, then there is data changes inside the database, the program wont update automatically....

Comment: The databaseSnapshot1 is refer to dataSnapshot.getChildren() right?

Comment: 1) Good catch on `dataSnapshot1`, that should be `dataSnapshot` indeed (not `getChildren()`). I updated the code in my answer. 2) When there are changes to a child, the `onChildChanged` method will be called. If you want to display changes, you'll need to implement that too, and probably the same for `onChildRemoved` and `onChildMoved`.